# Error on build but no compile errors

Tags: c++

I am having some trouble with my homework and could use your help.

I am getting some sort of error when I try to run my program. When i compile it i get the success mssage but when i try to run it i get a popup with the error "Unhandled exception at 0x011b18d2 in Project 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccd0." If anyone can help me i would appreciate it, thank you.

This is the code i was assigned to build on (this cannot be changed)

```
#include <iostream >
#include "stack.h"
using namespace std ;
int main ()
{
Stack < int > s1 , s2 ;
int element ;

s1 . push (1); s1 . push (2); s1 . push (3);
s1 . pop ( element );
cout << " s1 popped element : " << element << endl ;

s2 = s1 ;
s2 . push (4);
s2 . pop ( element );
cout << " s2 popped element : " << element << endl ;

s1 . pop ( element );
cout << " s1 popped element : " << element << endl ;

s2 . makeEmpty ();
s2 . isEmpty () ? cout << " s2 is empty \n": cout << " s2 is not empty \n ";

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

This is what i wrote to compliment the code above

```
template <class DataType>
struct Node{
DataType info;
Node<DataType>*next;
};

template <class DataType>
class Stack
{
public:
Stack();
void push(DataType elementToPush);
bool pop(DataType & poppedElement);
bool peek(DataType & topElement);
Stack(const Stack<DataType> &element); // Copy constructor
~Stack(); // Destructor
Stack<DataType> & operator=(const Stack<DataType> &element); //Overload assignment operator
bool isEmpty()const;
void makeEmpty();
private:
Node<DataType>*top;
Node<DataType>*header;
inline void deepCopy(const Stack<DataType> & original);
};

template<class DataType>
Stack<DataType>::Stack()
{
Node<DataType>*top=new Node<DataType>;
}

template<class DataType> // Remove the node at the front of the list and return the element
bool Stack<DataType>::pop(DataType & poppedElement)
{
Node<DataType>*ptr=top;
ptr=ptr->next;
Node<DataType>*ptr2=ptr->next;
top->next=ptr2;
poppedElement = ptr->info;
delete ptr;
return true;
}

template<class DataType> // Return the element at the front of the list wothout deleting it
bool Stack<DataType>::peek(DataType & topElement)
{
if(top->next==NULL)
    return false;
topElement=top->next->info;
return true;
}

template<class DataType> // Make a new node for the element and push it to the front of the list
void Stack<DataType>::push(DataType elementToPush)
{
Node<DataType>*ptr=top;
Node<DataType>*ptr2=new Node<DataType>;
ptr2->info=elementToPush;
ptr2->next=ptr->next;
ptr->next=ptr2;
}

template<class DataType> // Check to see if the list is empty
bool Stack<DataType>::isEmpty()const
{
return top->next==NULL;
}

template<class DataType> // Empry the list out
void Stack<DataType>::makeEmpty()
{
Node<DataType>*ptr=top;
while(top->next != NULL)
{
    while(ptr->next != NULL)
        ptr->next;
    delete ptr->next;
}
}

template<class DataType> // Deep copy
inline void Stack<DataType>::deepCopy(const Stack<DataType> & original)
{
Node<DataType>*copyptr=new Node<DataType>;
Node<DataType>*originalptr=top;
while(originalptr != NULL)
{
    originalptr=originalptr->next;
    copyptr->next=new Node<DataType>;
    copyptr->info=originalptr->info;
}
}

template<class DataType> // Copy Constructor
Stack<DataType>::Stack(const Stack<DataType> &element)
{
deepCopy(element);
}

template<class DataType> // Destructor
Stack<DataType>::~Stack()
{
makeEmpty();
}

template<class DataType> // Overload assignment operator
Stack<DataType> & Stack<DataType>::operator=(const Stack<DataType> &element)
{
if(this == &element)
    return *this;
makeEmpty();
deepCopy(element);
return *this;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see which line causes the access violation?

Comment: 1. At least to start with, only implement what you need (e.g., you have a `Peek` that's never used), 2. If possible, use an existing collection (e.g., `std::vector`) as the storage for your stack, and 3. build little pieces, and only move on to another when you're sure one works correctly.

Comment: Your teacher uses weird spacing!

Comment: @HairOfTheDog I did use a debugger and it comes back as a successful build, but when i run it i get the error

Comment: @Joe the debugger is for evaluating program state *at run time*. The *compiler* is what does the build and gives *compiler* errors.

Comment: @Joe Adam spent a lot of time reviewing your code and explaining where the problems are. Be sure to give him credit by accepting and upvoting his answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I got pushback on my previous answer. Maybe this one will be better received. If you don't like my choice of white space, that is what pretty-printers are for. The code below is the original code reformatted. My thoughts are included as interlinear gloss.

`Node` is an implementation detail of your `Stack`. It should be scoped as a private type declaration, putting here pollutes the namespace. Also, if this class had a constructor that either initialized `next` to `nullptr` or required it to be set explicitly, some bugs, such as the one you found, would be easier to diagnose. As it stands, after `Node` is constructed, `next` can point to a random memory location.

```
template <class DataType>
struct Node {
  DataType info;
```

Consider using a smart pointer here.

```
  Node<DataType>* next; };

template <class DataType>
class Stack {
public:
  Stack();
```

The argument should be `const&` to avoid extra copying.

```
  void push(DataType elementToPush);
  bool pop(DataType& poppedElement);
```

This can be a `const` method.

```
  bool peek(DataType& topElement);
```

`element` is a poor name. The copy constructor copies an entire stack, not just an element.

```
  Stack(const Stack<DataType>& element); // Copy constructor
  ~Stack(); // Destructor
  Stack<DataType>& operator=(const Stack<DataType>&
                             element);  //Overload assignment operator
  bool isEmpty() const;
  void makeEmpty();
private:
```

Consider using a smart pointer here.

```
  Node<DataType>* top;
```

`header` is not used. It should be deleted.

```
  Node<DataType>* header;
  inline void deepCopy(const Stack<DataType>& original); };

template<class DataType>
Stack<DataType>::Stack() {
```

`top` should be initialized to `nullptr` in a member initialization list. The empty node you
are using here is not required, it makes you code more complex, and you end up leaking it later.

Also, this is a major bug. You are assigning to a local here, not the member variable!

```
  Node<DataType>* top = new Node<DataType>; }

template<class DataType> // Remove the node at the front of the list and return the element
bool Stack<DataType>::pop(DataType& poppedElement) {
```

If you want `ptr` to be `top->next` just say that.

```
  Node<DataType>* ptr = top;
  ptr = ptr->next;
```

This `ptr2` variable is not needed. You just need `top->next = top->next->next`. Also note that the empty head element is adding noise here.

```
  Node<DataType>* ptr2 = ptr->next;
  top->next = ptr2;
  poppedElement = ptr->info;
  delete ptr;
```

You need to have tested for underflow to return `false` in that case.

```
  return true; }
```

People are pretty forgiving about comments, but it is best if they are properly spelled and punctuated.

```
template<class DataType> // Return the element at the front of the list wothout deleting it
bool Stack<DataType>::peek(DataType& topElement) {
  if (top->next == NULL) {
    return false; }

  topElement = top->next->info;
  return true; }

template<class DataType> // Make a new node for the element and push it to the front of the list
void Stack<DataType>::push(DataType elementToPush) {
```

This variable is meaningless, just use `top`.

```
  Node<DataType>* ptr = top;
```

`ptr2` can be constructed with the values you need instead of being mutated afterwards. Try `auto ptr2 = new Node<DataType> { elementToPush, ptr->next };`. Also, consider using a smart pointer.

```
  Node<DataType>* ptr2 = new Node<DataType>;
  ptr2->info = elementToPush;
  ptr2->next = ptr->next;
  ptr->next = ptr2; }

template<class DataType> // Check to see if the list is empty
bool Stack<DataType>::isEmpty()const {
  return top->next == NULL; }
```

This function is just broken. You need to rethink it.

```
template<class DataType> // Empry the list out
void Stack<DataType>::makeEmpty() {
  Node<DataType>* ptr = top;

  while (top->next != NULL) {
```

One `while` loop will do you. Lists are linear, not square.

```
    while (ptr->next != NULL) {
```

This statement has no effect; it does nothing. Your compiler should be warning about that, turn on warnings, or turn the warning level up.

```
      ptr->next; }

    delete ptr->next; } }
```

This is very broken too. You need to iterate over two lists, so you need two iterator variables. One iterator is the stuff you are copying and just needs to be bumped along as you read it. The other is mutating the current object and has slightly more book keeping.

```
template<class DataType> // Deep copy
inline void Stack<DataType>::deepCopy(const Stack<DataType>& original) {
  Node<DataType>* copyptr = new Node<DataType>;
  Node<DataType>* originalptr = top;

  while (originalptr != NULL) {
    originalptr = originalptr->next;
    copyptr->next = new Node<DataType>;
    copyptr->info = originalptr->info; } }

template<class DataType> // Copy Constructor
Stack<DataType>::Stack(const Stack<DataType>& element) {
  deepCopy(element); }

template<class DataType> // Destructor
Stack<DataType>::~Stack() {
```

Note that `makeEmpty` does not delete your empty head node. This will leak a node.

```
  makeEmpty(); }

template<class DataType> // Overload assignment operator
Stack<DataType>& Stack<DataType>::operator=(const Stack<DataType>&
    element) {
  if (this == &element) {
    return *this; }

  makeEmpty();
```

Again, your empty head node is causing pain here. Does `deepCopy` create the empty head node or not? Your use of it in your copy constructor seems to assume it does. Your use of it here seems to assume it does not. In fact, I think the problem is that `makeEmpty` does not delete your head node, if it did, both this function and your destructor would work properly.

```
  deepCopy(element);
  return *this; }
```

Comment: @HairOfTheDog, Thanks. Although I will point out there is a stack exchange for code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

What you are seeing is a run-time error, not a build error. And your IDE reports a successful build, not your debugger. Your debugger is what allows you to trace through the program line-by-line and inspect the values of your variables.

Compare your code to the following.

```
template <class DataType>
struct Node {
  DataType info;
  Node<DataType>* next; };

template <class DataType>
class Stack {
public:
  Stack();
  void push(DataType elementToPush);
  bool pop(DataType& poppedElement);
  bool peek(DataType& topElement);
  Stack(const Stack<DataType>& element);
  ~Stack();
  Stack<DataType>& operator=(const Stack<DataType>& element);
  bool isEmpty()const;
  void makeEmpty();
private:
  Node<DataType>* top;
  inline void deepCopy(const Stack<DataType>& original); };


// Linked list stack implementation.
template<class DataType>
Stack<DataType>::Stack() {
  // Head of the list. Not actually used for anything. Why is this here?
  top = new Node<DataType>; }

// Remove the node at the front of the list and return the element
// Does not check for underflow.
template<class DataType>
bool Stack<DataType>::pop(DataType& poppedElement) {
  Node<DataType>* ptr = top->next;
  Node<DataType>* ptr2 = ptr->next;
  top->next = ptr2;
  poppedElement = ptr->info;
  delete ptr;
  return true; }

// Return the element at the front of the list without deleting it
template<class DataType>
bool Stack<DataType>::peek(DataType& topElement) {
  if (top->next == NULL) {
    return false; }

  topElement = top->next->info;
  return true; }

// Make a new node for the element and push it to the front of the list
template<class DataType>
void Stack<DataType>::push(DataType elementToPush) {
  Node<DataType>* ptr2 = new Node<DataType>;
  ptr2->info = elementToPush;
  ptr2->next = top->next;
  top->next = ptr2; }

// Check to see if the list is empty
template<class DataType>
bool Stack<DataType>::isEmpty()const {
  return top->next == NULL; }

// Empty the list out
template<class DataType>
void Stack<DataType>::makeEmpty() {
  while (top->next != NULL) {
    Node<DataType>* ptr = top->next;
    top->next = ptr->next;
    delete ptr; } }

// Deep copy
template<class DataType>
inline void Stack<DataType>::deepCopy(const Stack<DataType>& original) {
  Node<DataType>* origiter = original.top;
  Node<DataType>* thisiter = top;

  while (origiter->next != NULL) {
    thisiter->next = new Node<DataType>(*(origiter->next));
    origiter = origiter->next;
    thisiter = thisiter->next; }

  thisiter->next = NULL; }

// Copy Constructor
template<class DataType>
Stack<DataType>::Stack(const Stack<DataType>& element) {
  deepCopy(element); }

// Destructor
template<class DataType>
Stack<DataType>::~Stack() {
  // This leaks because the head node is still there.
  makeEmpty(); }

// Overload assignment operator
template<class DataType>
Stack<DataType>& Stack<DataType>::operator=(const Stack<DataType>&
    element) {
  if (this == &element) {
    return *this; }

  makeEmpty();
  deepCopy(element);
  return *this; }
```

Comment: A better answer would provide a prose explanation, not just say "compare your code to this [100 lines of code]". The fact that you've reformatted the code (what's with that brace style anyway? this is C++, not Lisp) only makes that comparison even harder.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, I created a new answer with more hand holding. Hope you like it better.